# Wordpress download counter in post card

Tags: wordpress

[Wordpress Download Counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD4RL.jpg)

I want to know about which wordpress plugin is this website to show download count as post card?
Have a look at the blue post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site uses the "Gridly" Wordpress theme and Bootstrap. I could not nail down how they're *getting* the download counts but the icons are Bootstrap glyphicons. One Wordpress plugin that would let you track downloads (which you'd need to do to get the counts!) is here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-download-monitor/ You should be able to substitute bootstrap and glyphicons for the display of the counts.